# Bulk delete of events - is such a thing possible?

Tags: civievent, api, sql, delete

We've had a bit of a mix up and imported the same set of events twice.  Most if not all of the duplicates have no participants (but I'm not 100% certain of that)

Is there a way to bulk delete these duplicates?  I can't code but I can use sql a bit

I've seen this suggested: "DELETE from civicrm_event WHERE id=1".  is that ok to use on multiple events?  Is it ok to use if an event has participants?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean you have imported the events twice (title, description, date, location etc), or that you have imported a list of participants twice?  How did you do the import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General advice is don't use SQL directly - use the API.  You don't have to write code if you use [cv](https://github.com/civicrm/cv) or API explorer.

Comment: woo hoo  that API explorer is a thing of beauty.. wish I'd looked at that before.. thanks for the suggestion.. and a huge thanks to the people who built it

Answer (score 0):

If you know your ID then you would most likely use IN (1,5,7,etc)

Comment: thanks Pete.. is it Ok to delete that way if the event has participants?

Comment: first delete the Participants via the UI or sql but be warned deleting via sql does not necessarily cascade down to remove all other related data eg Contributions or Activities related to the Participant registration

Comment: see Aidan's API answer for a better solution